# What does the phrase "dive into the details" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does the phrase "dive into the details" mean in the following sentence from a layout app:

*With simple templates, you can quickly create layouts for brochures, flyers, business cards, and more. Then **dive into the details** to combine unlimited layers and filter effects and align tables with complete accuracy.*

Does the phrase simply mean "customize the layout"?

Comment: dive into the pool; go into the pool; dive into the details, go into the details straight on. Lots of technical English uses metaphors like this.

Comment: I wouldn't call this "technical English" (which tends to use less figurative language).  This is "sales and marketing English".  It is meant to be engaging to get you, ultimately, to buy the product.  Metaphor is a rhetorical technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means something like, "start working at a more detailed level than the large pieces you started off with".

In a layout app, you can create the visual layout by moving pieces around so they are roughly where you want them, probably with drag-and-drop. Once that's done, you can edit the properties of each element of the layout and fine tune what each one does.

Answer (score 2):

From *[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dive-in-dive-into)*
*"Dive into the details"* means *"become occupied with the details"* or *"become involved in the details"*. They, as you pointed out, help you customise the layout further.

> Figurative sense of "plunge entirely into something that engrosses the attention" is from 1580s.
> [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/plunge)